# Using fullPage.js on homepage in angularjs application, must destroy on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullpage.js

I am using **fullPage.js** in an **angularJs** application on homepage only and no other page / route should get affected, In order to achieve this I am calling destroy on locationChangeSuccess event.

Am I doing it right or could there be any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a more generic question. Something like "using jquery plugin only in the home page when using angular.js".

I'm no very familiarized with angular.js, but you probably can initialize the plugin from the angular side only when certain element exist in the DOM.

Something like:

```
if($('#fullpage').length){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
}
```